# updating a nested field in mongodb not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a model which has a field with nested fields, when I try to update the field it doesn't work. it still remail=ns the same. Below is the code with further explanations.

i have a model below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    typeof: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["studio", "hall", 
                "house", "mansion",
                "field", "room",
                "restaurant", "school",
                "church", "beach", "warehouse",
                "others"
            ]
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    time: {
        alwaysopen: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false
        },
        open: {
            type: String
        },
        close: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    idealfor: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: ["reception", "production", 
                "meeting", "performance",
                "dinner", "wedding",
                "party", "conference"
            ]
    }],
    rooms: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    toilet: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    amenities: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: ["electricity", "a/c", 
                "wifi", "sound system", 
                "private entrance", 
                "kitchen", "large table", "tv",
                "green screen", "Stage", 
                "changing room", "makeup room",
                "lounge", "soundproof"
            ]
    }],
    accessibility: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: ["wheelchair", "Elevator", 
                "on-site parking", "parking near by",
                "Stairs"
            ]
    }],
    isOpen: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: true
    },
    phonenumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

the problem is that when i try to update the `time.alwaysopen` field from `false` to `true`, id doesn't work.

below is the update route

```
// Edit a place
router.patch('/api/place/:id', isVerified, async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    const allowedUpdates = ["title", "description", "maxguest", "size", "isOpen", "rules", "rooms", "toilet", "price", "phonenumber", "location", "typeof", "time", "time.alwaysopen", "time.open", "time.close"]
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

    if (!isValidOperation) {
        return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
    }

    try {
        const place = await Place.findOne({ _id: req.params.id, owner: req.user._id })

        if (!place) {
            return res.status(404).send({ "message": "place does not exist" })
        }

        updates.forEach((update) => place[update] = req.body[update])
        await place.save()
        res.status(201).send({place, "message": "successfully updated" })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({ "message": "failed to update" })
    }
})
```

and below is the patch json request i make

```
{
    "time.alwaysopen": false
}
```

after sending the patch request, i still get the vaue of the `time.alwaysopen` to be true, but updating the field is fine.

below is the response i get

```
{
    "place": {
        "time": {
            "alwaysopen": true
        },
        "idealfor": [
            "production",
            "wedding"
        ],
        "amenities": [
            "electricity",
            "a/c",
            "Stage"
        ],
        "accessibility": [],
        "unavailabledate": [],
        "isOpen": true,
        "img": true,
        "_id": "604028e717314039402c2c10",
        "typeof": "studio",
        "location": "good news church, olufemi street, surulere, Lagos, Nigeria",
        "rooms": 2,
        "toilet": 2,
        "price": 1000,
        "phonenumber": "+2348125580085",
        "owner": "603e6b494e0df045745066a7",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-04T00:25:11.413Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-04T01:19:14.867Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "description": "the famous hotel",
        "title": "Royal habiscus edited"
    },
    "message": "successfully updated"
}
```

Please, what could be the problem?

Comment: Why don't you directly use the `findOneAndUpdate` command where you are currently using the findOne. You can do both the operation of find and update and if found update it.

Comment: @RoshanRaj i didnt use that because i am running a check to see if its a valid update they can make.